# Mysql select query with distinct option

Tags: mysql

My sql table is given below

id__________name__________class
11__________arun___________9
22__________anu___________8
33__________allu___________9

I want to select id and class values and the result should only contain one class one time only.when i use **"SELECT distinct class,id FROM `table` "**
class 9 is repeating.Is there any solution.

Comment: I dont think it should repeat since your saying distinct class it will only show distinct values 9 will not repeat 2 times. Plz check again

Comment: Which id do you want returned when there are more than one for a class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
SELECT class, id
FROM table
GROUP BY class
```

The `DISTINCT` option produces all unique combinations of the selected columns, not just the first column. Use `GROUP BY` if you need to make a subset of the columns distinct.

Note that this will select an arbitrary `id` from all the rows with the same `class`. So you might get

```
class   id
8       22
9       11
```

or

```
class   id
8       22
9       33
```

Answer (score 0):

`DISTINCT` in the `SELECT` clause results in all unique combinations of fields in the `SELECT` clause. Since (9, 11) and (33, 9) are unique, they are both returned.

Comment: i don't want distinct result.i only want class 9 once in the  result.what change i have to make it to get that